# How to upload file in a JSF application using JMeter

Tags: java, jsf, testing, upload, jmeter

I've been asked this time to also create a test script for file upload in a JSF application using JMeter. The generated script from blazemeter is as follows:

[generated script for input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjhFB.png)

The encircled value is the file name. I have noticed that the parameter was not created under "Files Upload" tab, so I have also tried to move the parameter to File Upload tab, using the generated content type in our application logs when uploading as Mime Type in JMeter:

[Jmeter file upload tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvTy7.png)

[Generated content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXiLL.png)

But it has the same result when I first tried the script where the file name parameter was still under "Parameters" tab (file name is null according to localhost application logs):

[Application log indicating that file name is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pANg.png)

The UI of the file upload is this. The user clicks browse button, picks a file then the name of the file is displayed in the input field (Import File). The user would then click the Import button to submit the form:

[File upload UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQKRo.png)

Am I missing a step or doing something incorrectly?

Thank you in advance! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of building a file upload request might be wrong, if you want to continue manual experiments I would recommend comparing requests which are being sent by JMeter and the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Apart from `${VIEWSTATE}` the requests should be exactly the same.

An easier option would be just re-recording the request (you can record only one single request) using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way of doing this is using [JMeter Templates](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) feature

   - from JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - expand HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare your browser for recording, refer your browser documentation in order to set up proxy using `localhost` as the proxy host and `8888` as the proxy port, the proxy needs to be set **for all protocols** with **no exclusions**. The relevant configuration for Mozilla Firefox (the only free and open source popular browser, moreover it has separate proxy configuration which does not derive from the operating system) would be:

   [image]
3. **Copy the file you will be recording to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**. If you omit this step JMeter will not be able to properly record the request. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details if needed
4. Execute the request in browser - the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler will be generated under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, I tried recording using HTTPS(S) Test script recorder, and after a few edits it worked properly in localhost. I also copied the difference to the generated script by blazemeter to make them identical. however when I run the blazemeter upload script, it was still unsuccessful [dropbox link for the recorded scripts](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a4mtxozggvxzd6v/AADvc2g95_ktU7p0NIjCUJm5a?dl=0)  I would be creating the test script for the application server where I need to use the company proxy to connect to, so I was using blazemeter chrome extension for recording.

Comment: Would there be any possible way to record script while using a company proxy? Or is there something I have missed when editing the blazemeter script to work properly like the generated script from HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder?

Comment: The http request used for the file upload are the following:

in blazemeter generated script: 6th http request; 

in jmeter Test Script Recorder: 7th http request

Comment: Look into [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) for both scripts, there might be differences in i.e. [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) or [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) headers. With regards to recording test using JMeter via corporate proxy - [it should not be a problem as well](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Comment: Upon checking, the jmeter generated script doesn't use a HTTP Header Manager, so I also removed the header manager in blazemeter script. I checked the request headers generated when running both scripts, and I noticed that there are discrepancies in Content-type request header. [Picture of request headers for both scripts. ](https://i.imgur.com/yyRZYxP.jpg) On the left side (jmeter) the highlighted strings are the same, but on the right side (blazemeter), they are different. Is it possible that the Content-type header is causing the problem...? If so, would there be a way on how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you for the link on how to set up JMeter to run via corporate proxy. As for the proxy setup, I would not be able to access the web application if I were to use jmeter http proxy protocol (localhost:8888) in my browser.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, after rechecking the scripts, I found out what was wrong in the blazemeter generated script. I did not check the HTTP Header Manager under the HTTP request I deleted the set Content-Type by blazemeter and it finally worked! Thank you very much for your help, I would not have been able to solve it without your assistance.